# T4 template to generate a typed dataset

Tags: .net, unit-testing, dataset, ndbunit

Is there a T4 template to generate a typed dataset?

I am using NDBUnit for testing and I would like to have the XSD automatically updated when I change my database schema. Ideally I would like the XSD to only contain a subset of the tables in the database.

Alternatively is there any command line tools, nant or msbuild tasks that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyGeneration has a strongly-typed dataset generator template and a set of command-line opts that enable you to invoke it automatically as part of your build process.  See http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx for more info, downloads, a link to the latest version, and the library of existing templates.

Also, because MyGeneration supports persisting your MyGeneration 'project settings' and re-running them from the command-line, you can save the input choices you make for your template (e.g., the subset of tables you want to select from your DB) and re-apply them when the template is re-run.